# IOS application communicating with Nitty ( decompression )

Tags: java, objective-c, gzip, netty, compression

Please help me to figure out the way for decompressing data received from Nitty version 4.0 server .
as the deflate function on the server side uses JDK1.7 gzip include Huffman algorithm and LZ77 .

so when the server sends the Data compressed for the first time i use the Gzip library :

```
- (NSData *) gzipInflate
```

{
    z_stream strm;

```
// Initialize input
strm.next_in = (Bytef *)[self bytes];
NSUInteger left = [self length];        // input left to decompress
if (left == 0)
    return nil;                         // incomplete gzip stream

// Create starting space for output (guess double the input size, will grow
// if needed -- in an extreme case, could end up needing more than 1000
// times the input size)
NSUInteger space = left << 1;
if (space < left)
    space = NSUIntegerMax;
NSMutableData *decompressed = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: space];
space = [decompressed length];

// Initialize output
strm.next_out = (Bytef *)[decompressed mutableBytes];
NSUInteger have = 0;                    // output generated so far

// Set up for gzip decoding
strm.avail_in = 0;
strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
int status = inflateInit2(&strm, (15+16));
if (status != Z_OK)
    return nil;                         // out of memory

// Decompress all of self
do {
    // Allow for concatenated gzip streams (per RFC 1952)
    if (status == Z_STREAM_END)
        (void)inflateReset(&strm);

    // Provide input for inflate
    if (strm.avail_in == 0) {
        strm.avail_in = left > UINT_MAX ? UINT_MAX : (unsigned)left;
        left -= strm.avail_in;
    }

    // Decompress the available input
    do {
        // Allocate more output space if none left
        if (space == have) {
            // Double space, handle overflow
            space <<= 1;
            if (space < have) {
                space = NSUIntegerMax;
                if (space == have) {
                    // space was already maxed out!
                    (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
                    return nil;         // output exceeds integer size
                }
            }

            // Increase space
            [decompressed setLength: space];
            space = [decompressed length];

            // Update output pointer (might have moved)
            strm.next_out = (Bytef *)[decompressed mutableBytes] + have;
        }

        // Provide output space for inflate
        strm.avail_out = space - have > UINT_MAX ? UINT_MAX :
        (unsigned)(space - have);
        have += strm.avail_out;

        // Inflate and update the decompressed size
        status = inflate (&strm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
        have -= strm.avail_out;

        // Bail out if any errors
        if (status != Z_OK && status != Z_BUF_ERROR &&
            status != Z_STREAM_END) {
            (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
            return nil;                 // invalid gzip stream
        }

        // Repeat until all output is generated from provided input (note
        // that even if strm.avail_in is zero, there may still be pending
        // output -- we're not done until the output buffer isn't filled)
    } while (strm.avail_out == 0);

    // Continue until all input consumed
} while (left || strm.avail_in);

// Free the memory allocated by inflateInit2()
(void)inflateEnd(&strm);

// Verify that the input is a valid gzip stream
// if (status != Z_STREAM_END)
// return nil;                         // incomplete gzip stream

// Set the actual length and return the decompressed data
[decompressed setLength: have];
return decompressed;
```

}

thus if you are familiar with Huffman algorithm of DEFLATE ( i hope ) 
next time nitty deflate the same string and send it i receive it but shorter than the first time , and i can't inflate it ,

is there a way to apply inflate as the Huffman Tree algorithm  and LZ77 as the Java Nitty Server ?

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have provided the data in the comments below, it is clear what is happening.  The second string is a continuation of the first.  You simply need to keep feeding the subsequent data to the same inflate instance.

The first string starts a gzip stream and ends with an empty block, but does not terminate the stream.  The second string continues with more inflate blocks that refer to the first string.

The second string isn't the end either.  There should be more after that, since it does not terminate the gzip stream either.  Eventually you should get a packet that finishes the gzip stream, in which case `inflate()` will return `Z_STREAM_END`.

Comment: im not sure that you got my question right , 
when the server compress the string ( tareq ) the result is 24 bytes . when the server compress the string ( tareq ) for the second time i got only 11 byte . ( due to Huffman and LZ77 algorithm ) 
how can i make me decompressor understand this action ?

Comment: I'm sure that you didn't try what I said.

Comment: i've just tried what you said , and I'm sure that it's not working ,
the first inflate works fine , but when i receive the second data inflate returns nil .

Comment: Please provide the 24 and 11 bytes in hex.  I would expect it to be 25 and 13 bytes, so you should check carefully if you have all the data.  25 corresponds to gzip (which `15+16` decodes), and 13 corresponds to zlib (which `15` would decode).

Comment: the first message i received : 1f8b0800 00000000 00002a49 2c4a2de4 e5020000 00ffff   (23 bytes)

the second : 2a815000 000000ff ff   (9 bytes) 

the string used on both times is ( tareq ) .

Comment: here is the Java Server code :


pipeline.addLast("deflater", ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibEncoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));
pipeline.addLast("inflater", ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibDecoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));

pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(
        8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));


pipeline.addLast("decoder", new MyStringDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new MyStringEncoder());

Comment: thank you for explaining the cycle .

now about my Deflate code . i use this constructor : deflateInit2(&strm, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Z_DEFLATED, (15+16), 8, Z_RLE) ;
and the deflate function :   deflate(&strm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
 
but my deflator each time gives the same first Data ( with the Gzip Header ) Is this the right code to use ? 

even my INFLATER not working probably as the second time the function status = inflate (&strm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH); returns -3

Comment: Post a new question.  The comments are not the place for new questions and answers.